# How to Change the UISlider to Vertical?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uislider

I am customizing an `UISlider` for my app. I want the slider to be in vertical orientation, but the default `UISlider` is in horizontal orientation. I couldn't find how to change a `UISlider`'s orientation.

How can I make a vertical slider in XCode?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

By default, a UISlider is horizontal (--). If you wish to make it vertical (|) then you must do this programmatically, probably with a `CGAffineTransform`. For example, you can add this snippet to `viewDidLoad` or wherever you deem appropriate:

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
slider.transform = trans;
```

Comment: Hello IT's Work But One Problem I Want Upper Part Is Down Down Part  Is Upper Understand

Comment: hardik, just reverse the rotation. i.e. `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2)`

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using auto layouts:

In your viewDidLoad, try:

```
UIView *superView = self.sizeSlider.superview;
[self.sizeSlider removeFromSuperview];
[self.sizeSlider removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
self.sizeSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
self.sizeSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
[superView addSubview:self.sizeSlider];
```

It does not work with constraints, so the trick is to remove the constraints for your uislider.
You might have to resize it manually by setting its frame property.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with :

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
slider.transform = trans;
```

because I had the code in ViewDidLoad method. Instead, I put the code in ViewDidAppear and it worked fine.

Edit: it doesn't have to be in the ViewDidAppear, ViewDidLoad works fine too (even better). You could disable auto-resize, or set a constraint for the slider you're rotating so the size doesn't change after rotation.

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 5**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Turn Slider Vertical 
    myslider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat.pi / 2))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).